# Today Extension iOS 10 Swift, Show Less

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, widget, today-extension

I have a problem with the Today Extension in Swift. The problem is about the function "show less", it seems that all the buttons and label that I have inside the widget are compressed on them self (keep a look to the screenshot).
What can I do? Some hint? 
Thank you very much. 
[First image compressed cause Show Less button pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrn0R.png)
[Expansed widget with Show More pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLcNR.png)

Comment: It seems that your constraints are setup like this, so with less space, everything gets compressed. You should design your widget so that its basic functionality is available in the compact mode, and the expanded mode gives more details. Bear in mind, that if someone were to use it on iOS 9, they wouldn't have the option to expand.

Comment: So you think that I should set the constraints, maybe just that one of the label, and then when you will push "show more" all the buttons will appear? But should I also add the constraints for the others buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proper constraints such that it works for both **compact** as well as **expanded** mode.

I used all the labels to setup my `constraints`:

[image]

`Constrains` list that you can use:

[image]
[image]